# How to manage the timezone for spring batch framework tables (BATCH_*) without changing the JVM default timezone

Tags: spring-batch

I have a requirement that my Spring batch table entries like BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION, BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION etc makes the timestamp entries(create_time,start_time,end_time etc) with GMT timezone but my batch process jvm runs with a different timezone (-Duser.timezone=CET). Since Spring uses the java.util.Date for getting these timestamp currently I don't see any other option for handling this without touching the 
-Duser.timezone. Please let me know if we have any other options currently available to handle this requirement or chances of Spring batch introducing java.util.time* classes (timezone aware) to handle the timestamp in future.

Thanks & Regards,
Balu R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with the latest Spring Batch v4.2.2 (at the time of writing this). There is an open issue for that here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1014

Comment: Second part of my question is answered. Now whether any recommended approach/solution available with the existing spring-batch framework, Eg:- Any custom implementation of JobRepository can solve this issue ?

Comment: I answered your first question by saying it is not possible currently, I don't see any way to customize this other than implementing the change in Spring Batch tables and domain model classes. And I answered your second question `chances of Spring batch introducing java.util.time* classes (timezone aware) to handle the timestamp in future.` by pointing to the open feature request.

Comment: Thank u Mahmoud. I didn't know the first statement was pointing to Qns-1.